# Saving video via mp4 format using cordova media capture on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the [cordova media capture plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) in order to use the video camera to capture video in an Ionic project. Works great except it records in quicktime MOV  (I am currently only working in ios).

Is it possible to record in MP4?

I think I would need to specify mp4 somehow in the options parameter in the capture command:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, options);
```

but when I try to get available formats this way:

```
navigator.device.capture.supportedVideoModes
```

I only get an empty array.

Comment: Maybe it helps:
https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-media-capture-mp4video